# Turn scroll event "off" after it has been fired three times

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a small script I am running to load images on scroll. I would like to stop loading images after the function is called three times.

Here is the script:

```
$(window).on('scroll' function () {
    feed.next();
    ltfeed.next();
});
```

Except I want the `on()` event to fire three times and then stop. 
So it would act like `.one()` but fire multiple times.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set a global variable to keep the counting.

Comment: just use Global variable. i.e Set some Flag variable in window objectand keep track, if count is = 3 , just .off() your scroll event.

Comment: @MayurRahul suggest you read the answers before commenting... ;)

Comment: yeah , any problem ?? please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a variable track how many times the 'scroll' event has run:

```
var tracker = 0;

$(window).on('scroll' function () {
    feed.next();
    ltfeed.next();

    tracker++;

    if (tracker == 3) {
        $(window).off('scroll');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var scroll_count = 0;

$(window).on('scroll' function () {
    scroll_count = scroll_count + 1;

    if (scroll_count <= 3) { 
                feed.next();
                ltfeed.next();
    }
    else {
        $(window).off('scroll');
    }
});
```